# Powershell Error - Set-Mailbox, a parameter cannot be found that matches AuditOwner

Tags: powershell, exchange-online

I'm testing some auditing in my dev tenant trying to set up the "SearchQueryInitiated" abilities from here...

[Get started with auditing solutions | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/audit-get-started)

Based on the above link I've tried to turn on the auditing for my global admin, AND I'm running it as global admin.

```
 Set-Mailbox "gloabaladmin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" -AuditOwner @{Add="SearchQueryInitiated"}
```

But it gives me the error **"Set-Mailbox : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AuditOwner'."**
I tried variations of it -

```
 Set-Mailbox -Identity "gloabaladmin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" -AuditOwner @{Add="SearchQueryInitiated"}
```

with the same error, I tried it in both powershell 7 and powershell 5.

And my Dev Tenant does have the Advanced Auditing Enabled.

I'd appreciate any suggestions, it's super frustrating - thanks!!